# for connection of R and Java

Tags: java, r

I have written a program in Java. But when I compile this program it shows an error
How to solve this problem?
the source code of the program is:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JavaGDExample1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rengine re;
    String[] dummyArgs = new String[1];
    dummyArgs[0] = "--vanilla";
    re = new Rengine(dummyArgs, false, null);
    re.eval("library(JavaGD)");

    // This is the critical line: Here, we tell R that the JavaGD() device that
    // it is supposed to draw to is implemented in the class MyJavaGD. If it were
    // in a package (say, my.package), this should be set to
    // my/package/MyJavaGD1.
    re.eval("Sys.putenv('JAVAGD_CLASS_NAME'='MyJavaGD1')");

    re.eval("JavaGD()");
    re.eval("plot(c(1,5,3,8,5), type='l', col=2)");

    re.end();
  }
}
```

it shows this error

```
No symbol for REngine
```

please reply

Comment: you have added required lib ?

Comment: Is "No symbol for REngine" the **complete** and **exact** error message? How are you compiling this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are getting 'cannot find symbol' error message when you attempt to compile this. In that case, it means that you have not added the relevant JAR file into your classpath.

You can specify the classpath as follows.

java -cp <PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB> <YOUR_CLASSES>

If you are using an IDE, you will have to add these JAR files as libraries into it.

Comment: If you don't have them already, the jars are available at [http://www.rforge.net/JRI/files/](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/files/)